# Give us a way to go back to the initial votes position after clicking to view breakdown

Tags: feature-request, vote-count

When clicking on an answer to see the vote breakdown, there is not any action to return to the initial position, or at least I can't find it. The only possibility is to change or refresh the page:

[image]

Comment: [MSO dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320620/6083675). I wonder if the userscript there still works.

Comment: yeap, is the same question, I didn't see it before

Comment: @Laurel and there's one here as well. :)

Comment: Have you tried F5?

Comment: @Mast is this some attempt for a joke?

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack No. I simply don't understand. Why is F5 so intensive you'd need a new functionality added instead?

Comment: For Mac users It is not just F5

Comment: What's it for them, CMD + F5?

Comment: Your question reaffirms my suggestion, much better to have an immediate response on the screen

Comment: @Mast part of overall better user experience. Those small things join to bigger and better experience, if done properly. Requiring users to reload in order to "reset" changes is not a good user experience.